# Awk regex matching problem

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I experienced a problem using regex with awk. In particular I need to find all words in a file that:

- begin with "un";
- are at least 6 character long
- end with two vowel

(these conditions must be verified contemporaneously).
I've used this regex

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ for(k=1; k<=NF; k++) 
                         if ($k ~ /^un.{2,}[aeiouAEIOU]{2}$/ ) 
                             print $k; }'
```

the problem is that sometimes works and sometimes not.
I've tried it with two files: 
test.txt

```
unaaaiuolaa
unaaaaaa
unbbaa
```

file.txt

```
unaaaiuolaa
unarmadio
```

Mysteriously the regex matches all the words in the first file but only "unarmadio" in file.txt (notice that "unaaaiuolaa" is the same in both files).

May someone explain me why?

Comment: One way that I could obtain your result is to change your invocation to Tom Womack's answer below, and add an extra space to the end of "unaaaiuolaa" in file.txt.

Comment: Why should I add an extra space? (however, that didn't change the result)

Comment: What version of awk are you using? I'm using gawk, and the `{2,}`, `{2}` expressions only work if I use the `--re-interval` flag. Probably not relevant for you as you got it working with one of your files (for me it worked with neither input without the flag, and with both inputs with the flag), but thought I'd ask just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As grok12 said, the problem was an empty space at the end of "unaaaiuolaa". Deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very odd construction to use a loop within awk; I'd just do

```
awk '/^un.{2,}[aeiouAEIOU]{2}$/' < file.txt
```

Comment: Although it can be odd, I'm pretty sure is a valid syntax. Besides your solution keeps matching "unarmadio" but not "unaaaiuolaa".

Comment: According to pholser's comment there may be white space at the end of "unaaaiuolaa" so perhaps this regex should end with } *$/

Answer (score 1):

A different approach below, if you have multiple words in a a line, use the for-loop approach given in your question (a common method to handle each item in a row given by the FS-variable). Check the length before applying the regexp, which uses a greedy operator for "any character" and then 2 identical character-classes to make sure an item ends with 2 vowels.

```
{ for(k=1; k<=NF; k++)  {
        if (length($k) > 5) {
            if ($k ~ /^un.*[aeiou][aeiou]$/) {
                print $k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```